# How to run ASP.NET application from another computer(same router)

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web application, I wanted to test the site from my other computer(connected to the same router as mine). I tried to access it from localhost:7927 (the port my web is running at) but can't connect.
What do I have to do in order to connect my web from my other comp?
Let me know if anything is incomprehensible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried `localhost:7927` from *which* computer?

If the application is running on Computer A, then Computer A can access it with `localhost:7927`.  That's because it's running on the local host.

Computer B, however, needs to use the access of Computer A.  If you try to use `localhost` on Computer B, it will look for the application on Computer B.

You need to determine what the IP address is for Computer A.  For example, if that address is `192.168.0.2` then Computer B would access the application at `192.168.0.2:7927`.

`localhost` is an alias for the current local computer's IP address.  It doesn't work across different computers.  A computer can access its own local IP address, but it's often easier just to use the `localhost` alias.

It's *possible* that Computer B won't be able to access the application on Computer A for other reasons as well.  If one of them is running a firewall that blocks access, for example.  If that's the case, you're going to have to look into it on your end.

Comment: Also, if you're running the site using the default VS developer web server, it doesn't respond to requests from anything other than localhost. To test from another machine, even on the same network, you need to at least run IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your  ip address instead of localhost.

Example:

> http:// 192.168.1.100:7927

If you don't know your ip adresss:
From command prompte, write ipconfig and you will see there.